# Stripe checkout with custom form symfony

Tags: php, symfony, stripe-payments, payum

I have a checkout form that I am using to send shopping cart details to different payment gateways like paypal using Symfony and [Payum](http://payum.org/doc/0.13/PayumBundle/custom_purchase_examples/stripe_checkout).

Now I am trying to send payment details to stripe in case user selects stripe checkout option. At the moment the integration with stripe is working fine, i can send the payment and get the response from stripe however in order to send credit card details to stripe i get redirected to `capture`

[image]

where i see the "pay with card" button and if i click on it the popup appears to enter credit card details

[image]

What I would like to do is allow user to add credit card details on checkout form that I have rather than the form you see on popup. Is it possible to achieve this? How can i use my own form to send data to stripe rather than using stripe popup?

I found a close example of the process in [this](http://sandbox.payum.forma-dev.com/payment/simple_purchase/authorize_net/prepare) and [this](http://sandbox.payum.forma-dev.com/payment/simple_purchase/be2bill/prepare) example. Is there any example for stripe? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe Checkout is designed this way. You see the button click it, fill all the required info and that's it.

If you want to fill credit card details earlier you can do that, but in that case you have to use

- Stripe "direct". Implemented in Omnipay and used via Omnipay Bridge
- You have to pass omnipay credit cards like this ([better way is not implemented yet](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/issues/206)):

  $order->setDetails(array(
    'card' => new CreditCard($data),
  ));

  - and use `$this->forward` instead of redirect. Because credit card is not saved to database you have to process them immediately. ([example](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundleSandbox/blob/ffea27445d6774dfdc8e646b914e9b58cbfa9765/src/Acme/PaymentBundle/Controller/SimplePurchaseStripeViaOmnipayController.php#L36))

Comment: Thanks, you are correct and I did the stripe implementation using omnipay bridge

Answer (score 2):

This is an example for stripe In Javascript:

Including Stripe.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

Setting your publishable key :

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('YOUR_PUBLISHABLE_KEY');
```

send data :

```
    Stripe.card.createToken({
      number: $('.card-number').val(),
      cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
      exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
      exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
    }, stripeResponseHandler);
```

response :

```
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
}
```

for more detail check this link 
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js

Comment: thanks but the question is related to sumfony payumBundle not custom php and js